# Deterministic Encryption on Contact.Name field Used in Where Clause causing Issue

Tags: platform-encryption

I applied a Deterministic case insensitive encryption on contact.name field, And whenever I use it in a WHERE clause of SOQL query, it throws me an Field 'Name' can not be filtered in a query call. I though if you apply Deterministic Encryption to a field you can use it in SOQL Where clause? Need help for this one.

Comment: I'd try [synchronizing data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_mass_encryption.htm&type=5) (or re-synchronizing if you've done it before) and see if that helps. If the encryption is truly deterministic, it sounds like a bug.

Comment: I wonder if the issue relates to the fact that Contact.Name is a compound field generated from the (Title,) FirstName, (MiddleName) and LastName values? Could you apply encryption on these fields instead?

Comment: The weird thing is documentation uses Contact. Name for examples in their soql query for deterministic encryption haha.

Comment: I'd contact support - the field is clearly set up to support all three flavors of encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When you encrypt contact name we're actually encrypting first name and last name separately. See the linked help article which explains the considerations for deterministic encryption, as it has a section dedicated to this and provides a workaround.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5

Comment: Yeah , I miss understood this part of Name vs First Name and Last name. thanks a lot